# Can't create firebase indexing due to this message This page has moved to new location. Please update your bookmarks

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

When I try to create a firebase indexing through the link that is created automatically it shows in a popup message "This page has moved to a new location. Please update your bookmarks." and it doesn't create the firebase indexing

can someone help me?

[a screenshot of the message shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NljMy.png)

Comment: This is because yesterday, on the Firebase console, the vertical menu item for the Database Services has been splitted in two: one vertical menu item for Firestore and one for the RTDB. The URLs have therefore changed. You should do as explained by DJ Hemath below.

Comment: It worked, I also have to make this change to the url ..google.com/v1/r/... to ..google.com/u/0/... , thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

My link was without the "database" word already, but when I changed the:

..google.com/v1/r/... to ..google.com/u/0/...

it worked. Note the "v1" and "r" is replaced in the working link for me.

I am using Flutter. Could be the Flutter Firestore package that needs updating, I don't know where the link is populated from exactly.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the url in the console, and remove **/database/**

For Eg,
Convert this

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/project-name/database/firestore/indexes?......
```

to,

```
https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/project-name/firestore/indexes....
```

Comment: i was able to fix, by changing the 'v1/r' to 'u/0'

Comment: my link didn't have the "database", But I hade the google.com/v1/r/ so I replaced with google.com/u/0/ and it worked! , thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

It indeed seems like something has been broken in a recent update. Thanks everyone for posting workarounds so quickly!

We have rolled back the change for now, so you should no longer be seeing this error. If you still see the error, please leave a comment below.